# Blackberry Device - getting set/default font size

Tags: blackberry, fonts

Is there a way that I can access the font size that is set on the handset?

I would like to use something like the following to setup the font on a screen:

```
setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 20));
```

replacing the 20 in the above with the font set in the application, up to a maximum that I'll determine.  I'm using JDE 4.5.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Font.getDefault().getHeight()
```